# javascript: define variable to object like a magic setter

Tags: javascript, object, setter

I am trying to set some variable to an object. But i want it to be set like the code below
is there a way to set a variable like this?

```
myObject = {};

myObject.save = function (var) {
  console.log(var);
}

myObject.users.save(); // must output 'users';
myObject.fruits.save(); // output fruit;
```

the save method is just an example method. it means that i need to chain a method on the variable string.

i trying to achieve something like that.
any ideas how to achieve that?
thanks

Comment: No there's not, you can't use properties that don't exists, and you don't have a `users` or `fruits` property, and if you did, the `save` method would still have nothing to do with those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `List` class for your `users` and `fruits` lists, and provide regular list methods like `add`, `remove`, `size` and etc. to make it actually like a list class, and define your save method as a prototype method:

```
var List = (function(){

    function List(listType){
        this.listType = listType;
        this._list = [];
    }

    List.prototype.add = function(item){
        this._list.push(item);
    };

    List.prototype.size = function(item){
        return this._list.length;
    };

    List.prototype.save = function(item){
        console.log(this.listType);
    };

    return List;

})();
```

then you can use it in your object like:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.users = new List("users");
myObject.fruits  = new List("fruits");
```

now you can actually call those two lines of code:

```
myObject.users.save(); // output 'users';
myObject.fruits.save(); // output 'fruits';
```

and you can also define a save method for `myObject` and actually call the lists save method:

```
myObject.save = function(listType){
    if(myObject[listType] instanceof List){
        myObject[listType].save();
    }
    else{
        console.log("there is no such a list named : " + listType);
    }
};
```

and call it like:

```
myObject.save("users");
myObject.save("fruits");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
var obj = {
    users: {
        save: function () {
            console.log('Users');
        }
    },

    fruits: {
        save: function () {
            console.log('Fruits');
        }
    },
}

(or)

var obj = {};
obj.users = {};
obj.users.save = function () {
            console.log('Users');
        };
obj.fruits = {};
obj.fruits.save = function () {
            console.log('Fruits');
        };
```

Comment: problem is i never know what to propery will be.

Comment: May be, you can explain the context so we can understand the problem clearly.

Comment: I building document storage system and for clean user friendly api. i want it like mongodb store method: db.users.save({name: 'somebody'});